# Doctrine2 Criteria() generate wrong MySQL query

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, criteria

when I use *\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()*

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
...
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('isPublished', 1))
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('isDeleted', 0));

$this->comments->matching($criteria)
```

and I getting error:

```
Message:
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.rating AS rating2, t0.text AS text3, t0.username AS username4, t0.isPublished AS isPublished5, t0.isDeleted AS isDeleted6, t0.dateCreated AS dateCreated7, t0.userIP AS userIP8, t0.user_id AS user_id9, t0.product_id AS product_id10 FROM product_comments t0 WHERE ((t0.isPublished IS ? AND t0.isDeleted IS ?) AND t0.product_id IS ?)' with params {"1":1,"2":0,"3":1123}:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 AND t0.isDeleted IS 0) AND t0.product_id*IS 1123)' at line 1
```

The problem is operand 'IS' in where clausule. It is not MySQL operand. (If I paste this query to MySQL terminal, and change "IS" => "=" - is all right)
Why Doctrine genetate such query? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing line 91 of Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister

from

```
Comparison::IS  => 'IS %s',
```

to

```
Comparison::IS  => '= %s',
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in doctrine fixed by upgrading Doctrine ORM to 2.3.5 or later.
Bug report at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2471
More discussion on the problem at
https://github.com/doctrine/collections/commit/3db3ab843ff76774bee4679d4cb3a10cffb0a935#diff-757942c669bf6be9910786b2558ad745

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
  expr()->eq('isPublished', 1)  and expr()->eq('isPublished', 0) with

 expr()->eq('isPublished', '?1')
 expr()->eq('isPublished', '?0')
```

Comment: Nop, this solution doesn't work. Problem isn't in param value, but in generate mysql query (I think so in another database (MSSQL, PostgreSQL))